# Java documentation search engine at chrome

Tags: google-chrome, search-engine, javadoc, google-search

I'm trying to add custom search engine to chrome omnibox, one of these which I wanted was Java Documentation. I failed and I have no more ideas how to solve it.

The search engine that I want to use:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/search.html
And I need link with variable '%s' at position of searching phrase.

+Maybe any better searching engine for Java Doc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right clicking the search engine in your link didn't work for me, neither did that URL.

Here are the ones I got to work:

**Search limited to Java 7 doc:**

http://search.oracle.com/search/search?search_p_main_operator=all&group=Documentation&q=%s+url%3A%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi&docsets=%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi

**Search in all Java SE:**

http://search.oracle.com/search/search?search_p_main_operator=all&group=Documentation&q=%s+url%3A%2Fjavase&docsets=%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do it,
if manually enter:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/search.html?search_p_main_operator=all&group=Documentation&q=&searchField=%s&docsets=

But there is second much easier way to do it, just press right click on search engine and click "add search engine".